# issues getting data to show on screen from SQL

Tags: sql, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

This is a React Js project that is using Axios, Cors, Express, and Node JS connecting to an SQL database.

I am trying to get the data from an SQL table and have it show on the screen either in a div or p tag each row on its own line. At this time I am able to get it to console.log inside my VS Code terminal from my server.js side as well as console log the data inside my browser console from my frontend of ProductList.js. I do not get any errors in any of my consoles just the data that I would like displayed on the screen.

The below is my server.js

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
cors = require('cors');


const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));



app.get('/collectors', function (req, res) {

    var sql = require("mssql");

    const config = {
        user: 'XXXXXXX',
        password: 'XXXXXXX',
        server: 'XXXXXXX',
        database: 'XXXXXXX',
        options: {
            trustServerCertificate: true,
            trustedConnection: false,
            enableArithAbort: true
            },
        }

    sql.connect(config).then(pool => {
        return pool.request()
        .query('select * from CollectorAssignment.tCollectors ').then(result => {
            console.dir(result)
            res.send(result)
        })
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log("error at line24: ", err)
    })

    sql.on('error', err => {
        console.log("error at line28: ", err)
    })
  });

app.listen(5000, () => { 
    console.log('listening on port 5000')
});
```

The below is my ProductList.js

```
import React from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

class ProductList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    error: "",
    data: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getCollectorList();
  }

  getCollectorList = () => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    return axios
      .get(
        'http://localhost:5000/collectors'
      )
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        this.setState({
          CollectorList: result.data.items,
          loading: false,
          error: false
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error("error: ", error);
        this.setState({
          error: `${error}`,
          loading: false
        });
      });
  };

  render() {
    const { loading, error, data } = this.state;
    if (loading) {
      return <p className="productList">Loading ...</p>;
    }
    if (error) {
      return (
        <p className="productList">
          There was an error loading the collectors.{" "}
          <button onClick={this.loadData}>Try again</button>
        </p>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div className="productList">
        <h1>Collector List</h1>
        {data.map(result => <p className="productList">{result.CollectorList}</p>)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ProductList;
```

Screenshot of my VS Code console data I get the same info in my browser console which is a total of 16 rows of data that I need displayed on the screen

[image: Screenshot of my VS Code console data I get the same info in my browser console which is a total of 16 rows of data that I need displayed on the screen]

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten this to start working for me here are the changes I have made to the two files I provided. I was calling a few areas improperly and found that I was looking at some ways for SQL and I am using SQL so some connections to the DB were different which caused some issues small syntax things mainly.

Server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const config = require('./src/dbfiles/dbConfig')

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ extended: true }));
var sql = require("mssql");

app.get('/getCollectors', (req, res) => {
    sql.connect(config).then(pool => {
        return pool.request()
        .query('SELECT * FROM CollectorAssignment.tCollectorsTest').then(result => {
            res.send(result.recordset)
        })
     })
})

app.post('/addCollector', function (req, res) {
    sql.connect(config).then(pool => {
        return pool.request()
        .query(`INSERT INTO CollectorAssignment.tCollectorsTest 
            (
                Active,
                FirstName,
                MiddleInitial,
                LastName,
                CollectorCode,
                CreationDate,
                CollectionTeamID
            ) VALUES (
                ${req.body.Active},
                '${req.body.FirstName}',
                '${req.body.MiddleInitial}',
                '${req.body.LastName}',
                '${req.body.CollectorCode}',
                '${req.body.CreationDate}',
                1
            )`)
            .then(result => {
            res.send(result)
        })
     })
  });

  app.post('/updateCollector', function (req, res) {
    sql.connect(config).then(pool => {
        return pool.request()
        .query(`UPDATE CollectorAssignment.tCollectorsTest 
                    SET ${req.body} = ${req.body}
                    WHERE ${req.body} = ${req.body}
                `)
            .then(result => {
            res.send(result)
        })
     })
  });

app.delete('/deleteCollector/:CollectorID', (req, res) => {
    sql.connect(config).then(pool => {
        return pool.request()
        .query(`DELETE FROM CollectorAssignment.tCollectorsTest WHERE CollectorID = ${req.params.CollectorID}`).then(result => {
            res.send(result.recordset)
        })
     })
})

app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log('running on port 5000');
})
```

ProductList.js

```
import "./userList.css";
import React from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { DeleteOutline, Edit } from "@material-ui/icons";


class UserList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    Collectors: '',
    collectorList: []
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getCollectors()
  }
  
  getCollectors = () => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/getCollectors')
    .then((result) => result.data)
    .then((result) => {
      this.setState({collectorList: result});
    });
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="userList">
        <h3>Collectors</h3>
            <table className="blueTableHeaders">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Active</th>
                  <td>Collectors</td>
                  <td>Aging Bucket</td>
                  <td>Program Code</td>
                  <td>Finance Company</td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
              </thead>
            </table>
        {this.state.collectorList.map((Collectors) => (
          <div>
            <table className="blueTableData">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th><input type="checkbox" name="Active" defaultChecked={Collectors.Active === false ? false : true}/></th>
                  <td>{Collectors.FirstName} {Collectors.LastName} | {Collectors.CollectorCode}</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <Link to="/updateUser:CollectorID">
                      <Edit className="editCollector" />
                    </Link>
                    <Link to="/deleteUser:CollectorID">
                      <DeleteOutline className="deleteCollector"/>
                    </Link>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </thead>
            </table>
          </div>
        ))}
        <Link to="/newUser">
          <button className="userListAddButton">Add Collector</button>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/deleteUser">
          <button className="userListDeleteButton">Delete Collector</button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default UserList;
```